# which class does jsp generated servlet extends

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

we all know that JSP is translated to servlet but when jsp is translated to servlet then does it extends HTTPServlet same as normal servlet or does it extends some other class?

Answer (score 6):

```
<%=this.getClass().getSuperclass()%><br />
<%=this.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass()%>
```

prints

```
class org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase
class javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
```

to me on Tomcat7